# Change image on button on MouseOver XAML (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on application and one requirement is to change the image of the button on mouse hover.

Below is my code for button,

```
 <Grid Margin="0 20 0 0" Name="ButtonsGrid" Width="300">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Button x:Name="AnswerButton" Style="{StaticResource hover2}"  Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="60" Height="60" Background="Transparent" IsEnabled="False" Click="AnswerButton_OnClick" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" >
                <Image Source="/Training.Project.Demo;component/Images/Answer.PNG"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Button>
```

And below is the style i am applying,

```
<Style x:Key="hover2" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <Border Name="border" 
                                      BorderThickness="0"                         
                                      BorderBrush="Transparent"                          
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Image x:Name="ButtonImage1" Source="/Training.Project.Demo;component/Images/Answer.PNG" Height="17" Width="17" />
                            </Border>
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage1" Property="Source" Value="/Training.Project.Demo;component/Images/answer-hover.PNG" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I am not sure what wrong am i doing but the above code is not working.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're setting both the `Content` of the button and its `ControlTemplate` to different images. Use one of those approaches instead, not both of them.

Comment: Can you please show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `IsEnabled="True"` and define the `Border` element in the `ControlTemplate` itself and not in a `ContentPresenter`:

```
<Style x:Key="hover2" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="0"                         
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"                          
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Image x:Name="ButtonImage1" Source="/Training.Project.Demo;component/Images/Answer.PNG" Height="17" Width="17" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage1" Property="Source" Value="/Training.Project.Demo;component/Images/answer-hover.PNG" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="AnswerButton" Style="{StaticResource hover2}"  Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="60" Height="60" Background="Transparent" Click="AnswerButton_OnClick" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" >
    <Image Source="/Training.Project.Demo;component/Images/Answer.PNG"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Button>
```

If you want a `ContentPresenter`, you should replace the its `Content` in the trigger:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border Name="border" 
            BorderThickness="0"                         
            BorderBrush="Transparent"                          
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="cp" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter TargetName="cp" Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="/Training.Project.Demo;component/Images/answer-hover.PNG"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The `IsMouseOver` property is never set to `true` if the `Button` is disabled.

Comment: Update: It is working now but when i hover over the button the existing image disappears and no other image comes in which means on mouseover it is getting blank but not getting updated with the new image. why is that happening?

Comment: Hard to say. Are you sure that the picture looks like expected? Which solution of the two proposed did you try?

Comment: Update: When i tried the second option it worked for me but can you please explain why the first solution didnt work was it because of ContentPresenter?

Comment: @FaranSaleem: Both should work. Your first approach didn't work beceause there was no Border element named "border" in the ControlTemplate itself and because the button was disabled.